# protobuf jar not getting downloaded to local maven repository

Tags: maven, protocol-buffers

In my pom.xml I have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in my settings.xml I have the below configured in the list of repositories in my active profile.

```
    <repository>
        <id>google-protobuf</id>
        <name>google-protobuf</name>
        <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java</url>
    </repository>
```

But in local .m2/repository I don't find any such directory path com/google/protobuf, and protoc generated java files in my project are not compilling, with the error

> java: package com.google.protobuf does not exist

The version 3.6.1. I have used in my pom.xml for the protobuf dependency matches that of my protoc compiler version.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Goddammit, restarting Intellij fixed it.